# Django only returning first value of for loop

Tags: django, post, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am running a for loop with a button that submits a url. The buttons are in a for loop and when I press one, it only returns the first url of the for loop.

My input looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />

<input type="hidden" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" name="url" value="{{ article.articledata.url }}">
```

and my view looks like this:

```
url = (request.POST["url"])
```

No matter which submit I press, I get the same request.POST value. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to post more code to see what's going on.  But, first, note that these two fields have the same exact `id`:

```
<input type="submit" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />

<input type="hidden" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" name="url" value="{{ article.articledata.url }}">
```

Perhaps you mean:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit{{ forloop.counter }}" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />

<input type="hidden" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" name="url" value="{{ article.articledata.url }}">
```

And, how is `article.articledata.url` sent?  You need to show those details from your view

Comment: it's so much code I tried to spare some. It's sent under a for loop: {% for article in articles %}. All the other article data is parsed out accordingly but when it comes to the input, it isn't correlating with the loop.

Comment: You should view the page's source code in your browser to make sure it is rendering what you think it is.